# asyncsocket "connectToHost" always succeeds and never returns a fail

Tags: objective-c, sockets, asyncsocket

I am creating a socket connection with objective C, using asyncsocket.  I do this using the "connectToHost" method.  I am trying to handle the case where the socket connection fails.  "connectToHost" is supposed to return "YES" when it connects sucessfully, and a NO otherwise.  For some reason, it is always returning a yes.  I even supplied a blank string as the host and it still returns yes.  Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Robin

```
BOOL connectStatus = NO; //used to check if connection attempt succeeded
testSocket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate: self];
connectStatus = [testSocket connectToHost: @"" onPort: 5000 error: nil];

if(connectStatus == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to connect to socket ");

}

else {
    NSLog(@"Connected to socket sucessfully, connectStatus = %d", connectStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [header file](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/RunLoop/AsyncSocket.h):

```
// Once one of the accept or connect methods are called, the AsyncSocket instance is locked in
// and the other accept/connect methods can't be called without disconnecting the socket first.
// If the attempt fails or times out, these methods either return NO or
// call "onSocket:willDisconnectWithError:" and "onSockedDidDisconnect:".
```

If you check [the source](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/source/browse/trunk/RunLoop/AsyncSocket.m) – for the love of all things holy, when working with open source software, **USE THE SOURCE!** –, you will see that the method you are invoking returns `NO` only when it fails to start the connection process. A return value of `YES` just says, "Okay, I'm trying to connect:

- "If things go wrong, I'll let you know by calling `onSocket:willDisconnectWithError:` and `onSocketDidDisconnect:`.
- "If all goes well, you'll get a `onSocket:didConnectToHost:port:` message, mmkay?"

Don't expect synchronous behavior from an asynchronous socket library.

Comment: point taken.  If it makes you feel any better, I did take a look at the source but just not thoroughly enough clearly.  thanks :)